# Trouble with simple GDL code

Tags: variables, idl-programming-language

I am writing a simple GDL(IDL) code for an introductory programming class. It is used to determine the velocity of a man parachuting in relation to time. It uses an Euler approximation and I keep getting an error that I am sure has something to do with defining my variables at the beginning but I don’t know how to. (I imagine it is something similar to the way its done in FORTRAN but that hasn’t worked for me.) Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
pro para

print,"enter inital time"
read,t(1)
print,"enter initial velovity"
read,v(1)
print,"enter drag coefficient"
read,c
print,"enter mass"
read,m

for i=1,10 do begin
v(i+1)=v(i)+(32-(c*v(i)*v(i))/m)*(h)
h=((t(i)+1)-t(i))
t(i+1)=t(i)+1
endfor

for j=1,11 do print,t(j),v(j)
endfor
end
```

When I try and run this code I get the error message

```
% Ambiguous: Function not found: T  or: Variable is undefined: T
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$          
% Ambiguous: Function not found: V  or: Variable is undefined: V
% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple adjustments. One: you hadn't defined the arrays t or v before assigning one of their elements (now t0 and v0). Two: h wasn't defined prior to its usage. Also, note you can start from 0 (instead of 1) in IDL.

I can't speak on the mathematics of the expression but I believe this is closer to what you were going for.

```
pro para

print,"enter inital time"
read,t0
print,"enter initial velovity"
read,v0
print,"enter drag coefficient"
read,c
print,"enter mass"
read,m

t=make_array(11,/double,value=0)
v=make_array(11,/double,value=0)
t[0] = t0
v[0] = v0

for i=0,10 do begin
    h=((t(i)+1)-t(i))
    v(i+1)=v(i)+(32-(c*v(i)*v(i))/m)*(h)
    t(i+1)=t(i)+1
    print,t[i],v[i]
endfor

end
```